# Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'eq; not found

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, animated-gif, gganimate

[image]

I am getting the below error while doing a gif animated ggplot in R in the below script.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
eq=read.csv("eq.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(eq)
eq<-eq%>%filter(Magnitude>=7)
```

~~ Kindly suggest

Comment: In your console window, I can see you used both `EQ` and `eq` in your code. Note that R is a case-sensitive language, so those would refer to two different objects in the global environment.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the csv you are attempting to read from cannot be found, so all manipulations on "eq" will then fail, as "eq" does not exist.

Are you sure "eq.csv" exists in the working directory? You can use `getwd()` and `setwd()` to respectively see and change the working directory.